# Is using Zener diode with a voltage divider sensible?

Tags: voltage-divider, zener

I need to convert a floating 12 V voltage to more or less stable 3.3V. So I bought the appropriate Zener diode. Now, since there's such a difference in voltage, I want to make Zener's life simpler and reduce the chance of it being blown up by using a 1:2.5 voltage divider. So I calculate the required Zener resistor value using 11 V - the lowest possible source voltage: `(V/2.5 - 3.3)/Iz = (4.4 V-3.3 V)/0.005 A = 220 Ohm`. And then I use this value to calculate the value of the other resistor required for the 2.5 ratio (147 Ohm).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fm7oUP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The question is: does this make any sense? Will this work, or will the R2 interfere with Zener's operation?
Is 4.4 V high enough source for 3.3 V Zener?

Comment: To answer you question I need 2 bits of information. What accuracy do you need from your 3.3V supply? How much current do you need to draw from the 3.3V supply?

Comment: What is the minimum and maximum current you need at 3.3 volts?  You have to take that range of load current into account when calculating the required series resistor (R1) and choosing the Zener diode power rating.  R2 is just wasting power.

Comment: @user1582568: Anything above 3.0 V and up to 5.0 will be OK; the higher the voltage - the better. I need to draw ~10 mA.

Comment: R2 just degrades the already terrible regulation.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: how so? The problem here is that V1 may produce short voltage spikes up to 50 and possibly even 100 volts. I feel that having the divider will drastically improve the Zener's chance of survival.

Comment: The divider will make survival more difficult for the zener diode. OK looks like we have some missing info about the 12V source too. What is its minimum voltage? How long may these spikes last (very important).

Comment: 11 V minimum, 15 V maximum. The spikes have random nature. It's the car's power supply, and there's no set parameters for the interference and transients because it depends on too many factors. There is an ISO 7637 standard for automotive equipment that sort of covers all the bases, it lists surge duration at 40 ms to 400 ms.

Comment: OK I will add values to my answer

Comment: Line regulation is determined by Rz/(Rz +Rs) where Rs is the source impedance. For a given zener current, Rz (dynamic resistance of the Zener) is fixed. In the circuit about your source impedance is 88 ohms with a Thevenin-equivalent source of 4.8V. With a 510 ohm resistor the current is the same. So if the Zener impedance is (say) 25 ohms, the regulation will be 1.8x worse.

Comment: I'm struggling to figure out where in your circuit you expect to be seeing that 4.4V you write about ...

Comment: I don't think spikes are your main problem. That part can take 100usec at 6A non repetitive. With a 510 ohm resistor (same zener current) that's over 3kV. Not a big deal. But 3.3V zeners don't regulate very well and your output voltage might end up being >4V at that current, you might well run into the abs max voltage of whatever you're connect it to on the spikes. Use a TVS, filter and a regulator like everyone else, unless your requirements are in some way constrained.

Comment: Increasing R1 would make life easier for the Zener; adding R2 will make it necessary to decrease R1.

Comment: @brhans: on R2.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: exceeding output voltage is not a concern. The part this circuit connects to is internally protected.

Comment: But you have a 3.3V zener in parallel with R2. You'll only see 4.4V there if that zener has already gone up in smoke...

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Do you have a strong objection against automotive voltage regulators? Zeners are not great regulators, as you are learning from these answers.

Comment: @brhans: I am replacing a 12 V source with a 4.4 V source by means of a 2.5 voltage divider. Don't see any contradiction here.

Comment: @uint128_t: none whatsoever. Can you please point me to one(s)?

Comment: @uint128_t: found one - Infineon TLE 4267, but it's kind of expensive and overkill current-wise.

Comment: No, you're not. When you use your 3.3V zener with the original 12V source, is it directly connected to it? No it isn't, because if you did that then one of the other would go up in smoke. So while that voltage divider *by itself* may produce 4.4V from a 12V source, you've directly parallel connected your 3.3V zener across R2. If you were expecting the voltage divider to be the source for a zener regulator then you need yet another resistor between the divider and the zener. This also completely ignores the fact that any current load on a resistor divider completely changes its output.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe You'll have to trawl through some [parametric tables](https://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-voltage-regulators-linear/2556290) to find exactly what you want, but here's an example of a 100Vin(max) LDO from TI: [TPS7A4001](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps7a4001.pdf).

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: Do you know how a Zener works?

Comment: I guess protected within limits or you could leave out the Zener entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that your current requirement is low and you do not need great accuracy then a zener is a cheap and viable solution. I would suggest filtering the spikes and using a circuit like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fldXoa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The values can be calculated when we have all the information.

R1 = 150ohms, R2 = 150Ohms C1 = 40V, 10uF.

The worst case automotive transient you will see will be load dump, most likely 40V for hundreds of milliseconds (this is an unlikely event and modern vehicles have central load dump protection, so very unlikely to see more than 40V for any length of time). Coupled transients can be higher voltage but last for tenths of microseconds and will be removed by the R and C. If the zener is 500mW or greater is will withstand load dump condition for any length of time). Use 1W resistors to give good transient capability. The circuit will work below 9V in and still allow 5mA to bias the zener. A 3.9V zener will meet your maximum 5V requirement and not be in danger of failing to give 3V (a 3.3V zener may be a bit close at low input volts).

Comment: That looks interesting! You've split the zener resistor into 2 in order to manipulate the capacitor's time constant?

Comment: R1 allows the source to increase or even drop to zero momentarily while the voltage on the capacitor stays repetitively constant. The time constant will be the parallel combination of R1 and R2 times C = 1.5ms. R2 will keep the zener current almost constant during short transients so the output will remain steady. You should of course include supply decoupling capacitors in you load circuit to decouple the 3.8V output.

Comment: The time constant is R1*C1, nothing to do with R2. I would add another shunt C after R2.

Comment: I didn't get the "decoupling capacitors in my load" part. What is there left to decouple on this circuit's output that C1 doesn't already take care of?

Comment: Does it make sense to limit the input voltage by means of a TVS diode parallel with D1 (or maybe with C1)?

Comment: No other diode is required as this circuit meets your requirements with minimum components. A capacitor is required at the output of this circuit (if your application circuit does not already include one) to provide for any instantaneous current demands. While your circuit draws a maximum 10mA average current, it is likely that there will be short term requirements for higher current. Digital circuits require quite large current pulses as logic states change for example. A capacitor across the output will supply these very short term demands and keep the voltage nice and steady.

Comment: @EJP The time constant of the circuit is the parallel combination of R1 and R2 times C1 (see my earlier comment), however I did do the sums wrong and only used 150ohms times 10uF, should have been 75ohms * 10uF = 750us. I agree about the capacitor, that's why I had suggested that it be added in the load circuit.

Answer (score 4):

R2 doesn't do a lot of good, except to increase the load current and decrease the overall efficiency. Consider, your circuit could be redrawn like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUOYpo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However what you can do is calculate the maximum current your load will require, then select R1 so that at maximum current, it drops most of the excess voltage from V1. Of course if the load current decreases, then less voltage is dropped across R1, but that's why you have the zener.

Or another way to think of it: if you omit R2, then you already have a voltage divider, formed by R1 and your load. So you just need to select R1 such that R1 and your load make the voltage divider you want, accounting for the range of possible currents required by the load, and the operating range of the zener.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Consider that R2 is in parallel with your load. Removing it will be like reducing your load, which in turn means you don't need as much current through R1.

A larger R1 will mean that any transients on V1 result in a lower current spike at the zener, than would have been the case with R1 and R2.

Comment: I can't freely manipulate R1 since I need to keep the zener in its working current range, no?

Comment: Removing R2 will allow a higher value for R1 while keeping the Zener in its working range.

Comment: @PeterBennett: yes, because the voltage will be 2.5x higher, and current will be the same - which also means higher power dissipation without the divider. Am I at fault?

Comment: Let's assume a proper design with just R1 passing enough current for the load. Now add R2. R1 must be reduced to make up for the current R2 draws, which means it will get hotter, more current at the same voltage drop. For the same load and zener current range, the zener dissipation will be the same.

Comment: You will have higher power dissipation with the divider, as you will have current through R2, in addition to that through the Zener, and through the load.  The addition of R2 will increase the current, and therefore power dissipation, in R1, as well as adding some power dissipation in R2.

Answer (score 2):

This page seems like much ado about nothing. It shouldn't be a big problem to create a zener shunt regulator for this particular situation.

Your R2 serves no practical purpose. I'd replace it with an electrolytic capacitor to lower the output impedance and provide a more constant output voltage that is more immune from spikes and brown-outs on the input. For a 10mA load, a value of 47uF will be just fine.

You didn't say how much your load current varies (if at all) from the 10mA nominal. Let's say it could potentially double to 20mA. And let's say the input voltage could potentially fall to as low as 10V. And let's say we want the zener current to never fall below 5mA otherwise voltage regulation will just get worse. Finally, let's use a 3.9V zener, as this will suit your requirement better.

R1's value must be calculated for minimum input voltage at maximum output current. So R1 = (10V - 3.9V) / (20mA + 5mA) = 244 Ohms. (Use a standard value of 220R)

The maximum current that will flow through R1 will be with the highest input voltage while the output is short-circuited. Assuming an automotive application, Vin could be as much as 14.5V. Maximum power dissipation in R1 will then be 14.5V * 14.5V / 220R = 0.96W, so use a 1W resistor.

Under normal running conditions the dissipation in the resistor will be: (12V - 3.9V)^2 / 220R = 298mW, which means the 1W size resistor will stay fairly cool.

The dissipation in the zener under nominal conditions will be: (((12V - 3.9V) / 220R) - 10mA) * 3.9V = 105mW, which is well within its capabilities.

Maximum dissipation in the zener will be at maximum input voltage and with the load disconnnected: ((14.5V - 3.9V) / 220R) * 3.9V = 187mW, which is still below its maximum rating. (I believe it's about 400mW.)

So, make R1 a 220R 1W resistor, D1 a 3.9V zener diode, and replace R2 with a 47uF electrolytic capacitor, and you're all good to go.

Or... you could just switch to using something like an LM317 regulator with a couple of resistors to set the output voltage, and a capacitor for stability, but that's another story.

Comment: I'm wary of using LM317, I suspect the transients might break it. Need an automotive-grade voltage regulator, I've only found one so far from Infineon. Quite possibly, I will go with it after all, just to be on the safe side...